# Не работает проверка в боте через регулярное выражение!

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, telebot

подскажите почему не работает проверка через регулярное выражение, по шаблону r"^с \d{2}:\d{2} \d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4} по \d{2}:\d{2} \d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}$" вот код. Я явно делаю что то не так, только не могу понять что! Подскажите как правильно сделать, буду благодарен за помощь.

```
   await message.answer(text='Укажи время Например:(с 21:30 24.11.2022 по 21:40 24.11.2022)', reply_markup=keyboard_staff_exit)
    await state.set_state(registration_of_the_application.first_time_last.state)

regexp=r"^с \d{2}:\d{2} \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} по \d{2}:\d{2} \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}$" 

@dp.message_handler(state=registration_of_the_application.first_time_last)
async def first_time_last_sg(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text == regexp:

        await message.answer("Неправельный ввод")
    
    else:
    
        await state.update_data(first_time_last=message.text)
```

Comment: ну так ты не применяешь эту регулярку, а сравниваешь введеный текст с этой регуляркой. Т.е. проверяешь, ввел ли пользователь точно такой же текст или нет. Конечно же нет

Comment: @Эникейщик а как правильно задать проверку? если не сложно напишите?

Comment: @DimaBastenuk, вот доки на нужную функцию https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match